# ffmpeg - Specify FC (center) instead of mono‏

Tags: ffmpeg, audio

I am trying to specify a single mono channel to be named 'Center' when viewed in Quicktime player, I know that technically specifying FC is mono, but in my user case I need it to actually be named 'Center', not 'Mono'. Is there someone who would kindly help me resolve this issue please, as I have searched everywhere to keep this work inside of ffmpeg without having to resort to a 3rd party application. I am used to applying ffmpeg patches, so if there is anyone who could easily write a patch, that would be amazing and very much appreciated. So I am specifying the 3rd audio channel to be labeled 'FC', so when viewing the file in Quicktime player, I want it to be labeled as 'center', not 'mono'. All the other channel labels are coming out named as I have specified, so I just want the center to come out. Here is my code, you'll see what I am trying to achieve:

```
ffmpeg -i /Users/kev/Movies/Test_descrete.mov -ss 45 -to 50 -filter_complex \
> "[0:1]pan=FL|c0=c0[FL]; \
>  [0:1]pan=FR|c0=c1[FR]; \
>  [0:1]pan=FC|c0=c2[FC]; \
>  [0:1]pan=LFE|c0=c3[LFE]; \
>  [0:1]pan=BL|c0=c4[BL]; \
>  [0:1]pan=BR|c0=c5[BR]; \
>  [0:1]pan=DL+DR|c0=c6|c1=c7[stereo]" \
> -map v:0 \
> -map "[FL]" \
> -map "[FR]" \
> -map "[FC]" \
> -map "[LFE]" \
> -map "[BL]" \
> -map "[BR]" \
> -map "[stereo]" \
> -vcodec prores -profile:v 3 -vtag apcn -f mov -y -c:a pcm_s24le /Users/kev/Movies/5_1_Sterero.mov
ffmpeg version 2.8.1-tessus Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.57) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)
  configuration: --cc=/usr/bin/clang --prefix=/opt/ffmpeg --as=yasm --extra-version=tessus --enable-avisynth --enable-fontconfig --enable-gpl --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopus --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-version3 --disable-ffplay --disable-indev=qtkit --disable-indev=x11grab_xcb
  libavutil      54. 31.100 / 54. 31.100
  libavcodec     56. 60.100 / 56. 60.100
  libavformat    56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 40.101 /  5. 40.101
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  2.101 /  1.  2.101
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/Users/kev/Movies/Test_descrete.mov':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt  
    minor_version   : 537199360
    compatible_brands: qt  
    creation_time   : 2015-10-17 18:55:33
  Duration: 00:01:58.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 170075 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: prores (apch / 0x68637061), yuv422p10le, 1920x1080, 160844 kb/s, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 24 tbn, 24 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2015-10-17 18:55:33
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
      encoder         : Apple ProRes 422 HQ
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: pcm_s24le (lpcm / 0x6D63706C), 48000 Hz, 8 channels (FL+FR+FC+LFE+SL+SR+DL+DR), s32 (24 bit), 9216 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2015-10-17 19:13:26
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
[Parsed_pan_6 @ 0x7f8d30419900] Pure channel mapping detected: 6 7
[Parsed_pan_5 @ 0x7f8d304196c0] Pure channel mapping detected: 5
[Parsed_pan_4 @ 0x7f8d304193c0] Pure channel mapping detected: 4
[Parsed_pan_3 @ 0x7f8d30419080] Pure channel mapping detected: 3
[Parsed_pan_2 @ 0x7f8d30418d40] Pure channel mapping detected: 2
[Parsed_pan_1 @ 0x7f8d30418a20] Pure channel mapping detected: 1
[Parsed_pan_0 @ 0x7f8d304182c0] Pure channel mapping detected: 0
Output #0, mov, to '/Users/kev/Movies/5_1_Sterero.mov':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt  
    minor_version   : 537199360
    compatible_brands: qt  
    encoder         : Lavf56.40.101
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: prores (apch) (apch / 0x68637061), yuv422p10le, 1920x1080, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 24 fps, 12288 tbn, 24 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2015-10-17 18:55:33
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
      encoder         : Lavc56.60.100 prores
    Stream #0:1: Audio: pcm_s24le (in24 / 0x34326E69), 48000 Hz, 1 channels (FL), s32, 1152 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc56.60.100 pcm_s24le
    Stream #0:2: Audio: pcm_s24le (in24 / 0x34326E69), 48000 Hz, 1 channels (FR), s32, 1152 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc56.60.100 pcm_s24le
    Stream #0:3: Audio: pcm_s24le (in24 / 0x34326E69), 48000 Hz, mono, s32, 1152 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc56.60.100 pcm_s24le
    Stream #0:4: Audio: pcm_s24le (in24 / 0x34326E69), 48000 Hz, 1 channels (LFE), s32, 1152 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc56.60.100 pcm_s24le
    Stream #0:5: Audio: pcm_s24le (in24 / 0x34326E69), 48000 Hz, 1 channels (BL), s32, 1152 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc56.60.100 pcm_s24le
    Stream #0:6: Audio: pcm_s24le (in24 / 0x34326E69), 48000 Hz, 1 channels (BR), s32, 1152 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc56.60.100 pcm_s24le
    Stream #0:7: Audio: pcm_s24le (in24 / 0x34326E69), 48000 Hz, downmix, s32, 2304 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc56.60.100 pcm_s24le
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:1 (pcm_s24le) -> pan (graph 0)
  Stream #0:1 (pcm_s24le) -> pan (graph 0)
  Stream #0:1 (pcm_s24le) -> pan (graph 0)
  Stream #0:1 (pcm_s24le) -> pan (graph 0)
  Stream #0:1 (pcm_s24le) -> pan (graph 0)
  Stream #0:1 (pcm_s24le) -> pan (graph 0)
  Stream #0:1 (pcm_s24le) -> pan (graph 0)
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (prores (native) -> prores (native))
  pan (graph 0) -> Stream #0:1 (pcm_s24le)
  pan (graph 0) -> Stream #0:2 (pcm_s24le)
  pan (graph 0) -> Stream #0:3 (pcm_s24le)
  pan (graph 0) -> Stream #0:4 (pcm_s24le)
  pan (graph 0) -> Stream #0:5 (pcm_s24le)
  pan (graph 0) -> Stream #0:6 (pcm_s24le)
  pan (graph 0) -> Stream #0:7 (pcm_s24le)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=   14 fps=1.1 q=-0.0 size=   10567kB time=00:00:01.00 bitrate=86563.8kbitsframe=   26 fps=2.0 q=-0.0 size=   23341kB time=00:00:01.50 bitrate=127471.3kbitframe=   38 fps=2.8 q=-0.0 size=   36133kB time=00:00:02.00 bitrate=148002.7kbitframe=   49 fps=3.4 q=-0.0 size=   47881kB time=00:00:02.50 bitrate=156896.6kbitframe=   59 fps=4.0 q=-0.0 size=   58482kB time=00:00:02.52 bitrate=190012.1kbitframe=   70 fps=4.6 q=-0.0 size=   70029kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate=191226.8kbitframe=   81 fps=5.1 q=-0.0 size=   81443kB time=00:00:03.50 bitrate=190623.1kbitframe=   92 fps=5.6 q=-0.0 size=   92871kB time=00:00:04.00 bitrate=190199.1kbitframe=  103 fps=6.1 q=-0.0 size=  104378kB time=00:00:04.50 bitrate=190015.0kbitframe=  115 fps=6.6 q=-0.0 size=  116801kB time=00:00:05.00 bitrate=191366.2kbitframe=  120 fps=6.8 q=-0.0 Lsize=  125425kB time=00:00:05.00 bitrate=205496.6kbits/s    
video:119787kB audio:5625kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.010789%
```